# java nio NoFilepatternException how to deal with spaces in file path

Tags: java, nio

i have a file located at C:\Users\abc xyz\Downloads\designspec.docx i want to copy this file in another directory using this code

```
String sourceFilePathStr="‪C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Downloads";
URI sourceFilePath = new URI(("file:///"+ sourceFilePathStr.replaceAll(" ", "%20")));

File source = new File(sourceFilePath.toString(),"designspec.docx");
File dest = new File("path to another directory","designspec.docx");
        try {
            inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
            outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
            outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
            log.info("copy complete");
        } finally {
            inputChannel.close();
            outputChannel.close();
        }
```

the above code is throwing exception

```
SEVERE: got NoFilepatternException {}
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 11: file:///‪C:\Users\abc%20xyz\Downloads
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
```

How can i resolve this exception please guide

Comment: new File("‪C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Downloads\\designspec.docx")

Comment: Usually, just like @NikiforosArchakis is suggesting. Why was your intention creating the `new URI(("file:///"+ sourceFilePathStr.replaceAll(" ", "%20")))` and then (maybe) a file from that URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do ?
You shouldn't need to make manual replace of whitespace by `%20`.

`File.toURI()` serves this goal.

Besides,  you issue is there I assume :

```
File source = new File(sourceFilePath.toString(),"designspec.docx");
```

You pass a String representation of the URI but that will not work with a `File` constructor that expects two `pathname` `String`s.

To resolve the docs from the folder, the URI is useless :

```
String sourceFilePathStr="‪C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Downloads";
File source = new File(sourceFilePathStr,"designspec.docx");
```

---

By the way, you could also use Path rather than File that is a better designed API :

```
Path parentPath = Paths.get("‪C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Downloads");
Path filePath = Paths.get(parentPath, "designspec.docx");
```

Comment: also i tried String sourceFilePathStr="‪C:\\Users\\abc xyz\\Downloads";
File source = new File(sourceFilePath,"designspec.docx"); but  this gives exception java.lang.NullPointerException at  this line inputChannel.close();

Comment: @swaheed there was a typo which you've copied into your code. See my edit.

Comment: exception remains there

Comment: @swaheed add a guard condition: `if (inputChannel != null) inputChannel.close();` - or better still, don't use `finally` but use `try-with-resources` instead.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for the fix about the typo on the variable name :)